# Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed Code: 6001 Reason [BLANK]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm getting the following message in my VM Ubuntu using GCP when I need to download a big snap shot (100GB). The message keeps coming up after about an hour of uploading. Notice there is no Reason given.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

[image: Error Message]